# Active Record - duplicate attribute value even with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with a uniqueness validation based on a scope (I'm using Rails 5):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :n_pacote, scope: :ecg_id
```

Even with that validation, I noticed that are duplicated `n_pacote` values for a same `ecg_id`. I also noticed that they were created almost at the same time:

```
[Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:59 -03 -03:00, Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:58 -03 -03:00, Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:58 -03 -03:00]
```

They're created from an api call that may be called multiple times. How can I fix that? Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Here's all attributes for the 3 records that have the same `n_pacote` value for the same `ecg_id`:

```
{"id"=>32289, "ecg_id"=>29, "leitura"=>[170, 69, 85, 81, 69, 85, 81, 69, 85, 81, 70, 102, 98, 70, 102, 98, 70, 102, 98, 71, 119, 115, 71, 119, 115, 71, 119, 115, 72, 136, 132, 72, 136, 132, 72, 136, 132, 73, 153, 149, 73, 153, 149, 73, 153, 149], "posprocessada"=>nil, "created_at"=>Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:59 -03 -03:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:59 -03 -03:00, "n_pacote"=>1620}
{"id"=>32276, "ecg_id"=>29, "leitura"=>[170, 69, 85, 81, 69, 85, 81, 69, 85, 81, 70, 102, 98, 70, 102, 98, 70, 102, 98, 71, 119, 115, 71, 119, 115, 71, 119, 115, 72, 136, 132, 72, 136, 132, 72, 136, 132, 73, 153, 149, 73, 153, 149, 73, 153, 149], "posprocessada"=>nil, "created_at"=>Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:58 -03 -03:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:58 -03 -03:00, "n_pacote"=>1620}
{"id"=>32256, "ecg_id"=>29, "leitura"=>[170, 69, 85, 81, 69, 85, 81, 69, 85, 81, 70, 102, 98, 70, 102, 98, 70, 102, 98, 71, 119, 115, 71, 119, 115, 71, 119, 115, 72, 136, 132, 72, 136, 132, 72, 136, 132, 73, 153, 149, 73, 153, 149, 73, 153, 149], "posprocessada"=>nil, "created_at"=>Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:58 -03 -03:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 05 Jul 2018 14:07:58 -03 -03:00, "n_pacote"=>1620}
```

Comment: Can you print the actual records (with all the attributes) instead of just their created_at times?

Comment: yeah, sure. Gonna update the answer

Comment: Which database and what does the model look like? In particular, how is `leitura` being handled? Do you have a uniqueness constraint inside the database? Can you reproduce this problem in your test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing similar issue but later I used db level uniqueness to avoid this one. Rails validation isn't 100% reliable when comes to uniqueness.

To be on safer side, add this validation on your db (MySQL ex).

```
add_index :table_name, [:n_pacote, :ecg_id], unique: true
```

Comment: Thank you, saw something like that on a post and I already did that for performance, but didn't put the unique clausule. Gonna try that